# 1.93 GB for 133 photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have an iPhone SE and I wonder how my device uses 1.93 GB for only 133 stored photos? This is the information I get to the 'storage' part of my phone, where it shows how much storage each app is using. In addition, only 0.53 GB of iCloud storage is used. How is this possible?

p.s. I had live photos enabled but this should only be applied for at most half of the photos I've taken. Wish there was a way to turn it off for all photos in one click (I use Windows sadly)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article:

https://www.cnet.com/news/iphone-6s-camera-filesizes-4k-live-photos-hdr/

The iPhone SE has a 12MP camera. In some conditions a single photo can result in four files - a still and a live photo, plus an HDR version of each.

1.93GB for 133 photos works out to about 14.5 MB per photo, which sounds a little high, but is within reason.